# ESP32-Cam GPIO remote control and video feed

Tags: gpio, remote-control, esp32, video-transmitter

Is it possible to control the ESP32-Cam GPIO from the web? Just like a "normal" ESP32 can create a website with buttons that turn on and off certain GPIOs

Was wondering because I can't find anything on the internet it only shows the normal ESP32

**Note:** I have ESP32M compatible with CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER, and wanted to transmite video feed from the esp to a website and on the same website having buttons that control the GPIO pins for that esp32-cam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the ESP32CAM can do all the things that the regular ESP32 can do, you just don't have access to as many GPIO. Only GPIO 2,4,12-16 are broken out to pins on the ESP32-CAM.

Comment: many thanks! It's all good to me since I only want to control a 4 relay module so I conly need 4 pins. Is the code different or the way you create the webpage is exactly the same?

Comment: @AndréClérigo An ESP32Cam is a regular ESP32 with some camera hardware stuck to it. If you know how to create code to control relays via a website on a regular ESP32, you can do the same with an ESP32Cam.

Comment: Awesome, thx for the help!